# Reading same data frame in a loop in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to Shiny. Suppose I have a function which needs to run in a loop. It takes two inputs, one changes, the other is a data frame hat does not change. To be specific, I will write a simplified function and inputs.

```
vec1 = rnorm(100)
vec2 = rnorm(100)


input = data.frame(vec1,vec2)


trial1 = function(input,b){
  vec1 = input$vec1
  return(vec1 + b)
}


trial2 = function(n,input){
d = rep(0,n)
for(i in 1:n){
b = rnorm(100)
d[i] = b + trial1(input = input, b = b) 
}
return(mean(d))
}
```

In this code, the input dataframe is read repeatedly in the loop slowing down the code. Can reactivity in shiny be used so that vec1 is read off from the input only once since input is unchanging in each loop? Will making trial1 reactive do the job(and 'input' coming in as input or another reactive function/value)?

Answer (score 0):

Generally for an R-Shiny application, most of your reactivity is within the server function

```
server <- function(input, output) {
   # your reactive components
}
```

You can always make a global variable that gets initialized outside this shiny server function

vec1 <<- #read in your data frame

And access that within the server block, so you're only reading it once

Comment: In this case, trial1 is also a user defined function and will be taken as an input. The user will most definitely read off vec1 from the input data frame (before using it for other purposes in his function) and not as a global variable. I have just taken the simplest function which illustrates the problem.

Comment: Then you'll need to get a bit more sophisticated, and cache the vector. So every time it triggers, you'll need to check whether the input parameter has changed vs. the last time it triggered. If so, regenerate vec1, otherwise keep vec1 as it was previously

Comment: How do I cache the vector without getting inside the trial1 function? Note that in this function (trial1), the output depends only on the data frame input. That may not be the case. I will just change the example a bit to make my point a bit clearer.